# Adding a default value in dropdownlist after binding with database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I binded my ddl to my database as below, but how can I add a default text on top of the binded values so that it appears as:

```
Select Color ---> default text
Red ---> database value
Blue ---> database value
Green ---> database value
```

Code:

```
    DropDownList ddlSize = (DropDownList)FormView_Product.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("ddlSize");
    CommerceEntities db = new CommerceEntities();

    ddlColor.DataSource = from p in db.ProductTypes
                                      where p.ProductID == pID
                                      orderby p.Color 
                                      select new { p.Color };
    ddlColor.DataTextField = "Color";
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

After data-binding, do this:

```
ddlColor.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select","NA")); //updated code
```

Or follow Brian's second suggestion if you want to do it in markup.

You should probably add a RequiredFieldValidator control and set its InitialValue to "NA".

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator .. ControlToValidate="ddlColor" InitialValue="NA" />
```

Answer (score 15):

You can do it programmatically:

```
ddlColor.DataSource = from p in db.ProductTypes
                                  where p.ProductID == pID
                                  orderby p.Color 
                                  select new { p.Color };
ddlColor.DataTextField = "Color";
ddlColor.DataBind();
ddlColor.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select", "NA"));
```

Or add it in markup as:

```
<asp:DropDownList .. AppendDataBoundItems="true">
   <Items>
       <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="" />
   </Items>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Your programmatic code will not make your "Select" item the defult or top item. It will simply be at the bottom of the list and the first item in the list will be selected, unless he otherwise sets the `SelectedValue`. See my answer for details.

Comment: Cool. If you just need an empty text & value as your default value, you even don't need to add any List Items . AppendDataBoundItems="True" will do the work. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can add it programmatically or in the markup, but if you add it programmatically, rather than `Add` the item, you should `Insert` it as position zero so that it is the first item:

```
ddlColor.DataSource = from p in db.ProductTypes
                      where p.ProductID == pID
                      orderby p.Color
                      select new { p.Color };
ddlColor.DataTextField = "Color";
ddlColor.DataBind();
ddlColor.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Color", "");
```

The default item is expected to be the first item in the list. If you just `Add` it, it will be on the bottom and will not be selected by default.

Answer (score 2):

design

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlArea" DataSourceID="ldsArea" runat="server" ondatabound="ddlArea_DataBound" />
```

codebehind

```
protected void ddlArea_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddlArea.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided by Justin should work. To be sure making use of `SelectedIndex` property will also help.

```
ddlColor.DataSource = from p in db.ProductTypes
                      where p.ProductID == pID
                      orderby p.Color
                      select new { p.Color };

ddlColor.DataTextField = "Color";
ddlColor.DataBind();

ddlColor.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Color", ""); 
ddlColor.SelectedIndex = 0;
```