# Need to set 1st value as select in Drop down list when the data source is table in database

Tags: asp.net

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_Role" runat="server" DataSourceID="Sql_role" 
                DataTextField="Role_Name" DataValueField="Role_ID">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Sql_role" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Mytime_role %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Role_Alert]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Rfv_role" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddl_role"
                Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="*Role is Required field" Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Red"
                InitialValue="0"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

it gives only the starting  text in database table as first value in Drop down list .so i need select as default one then the remaining list as usual

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625356/adding-a-default-value-in-dropdownlist-after-binding-with-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the selectedItem of the dropdownlist after the DataBind method.

```
dlTest.DataSource = // some datasource;
dlTest.DataBind();
dlTest.Items.FindByValue(search_value).Selected = true;
```

You can search for the item, either using FindByText or FindByValue. Alternatively, if you could store the selected item text/value, then you can set the dropdownlist selected item in the DataBound event. This will be fired after the data has been binded to dropdownlist.

```
protected void dlTest_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    dlTest.Items.FindByValue(search_value).Selected = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListID" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server">
  <asp:ListItem Text="Default text" Value="Default value" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Add a default item and also attribute AppendDataBoundItems="true"