# sql query for escape first record display decending order

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to right query

```sql
SELECT '0' AS PropertyDetailId, 'Select PropertyDetail' as PropertyName 
UNION SELECT PropertyDetailId,PropertyDetail.PropertyName 
FROM PropertyDetail join SiteDetail ON 
PropertyDetail.SiteDetailId = SiteDetail.SiteDetailId WHERE 
    PropertyDetail.IsActive = 1 
    AND PropertyDetail.SiteId = 6 
    AND SiteDetail.IsActive = 1 
    AND CustomerId = 0
ORDER BY PropertyName
```

---

But my `PropertyDetailId = 0` come under the dropdown.
I want solution for that my first record escape from Order command

Comment: do you want PropertyDetailId = 0 record to come in the last??

Comment: I would do this on client side, it is just insert item to index 0 of the dropdown http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625356/adding-a-default-value-in-dropdownlist-after-binding-with-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use "row number" field like this:

```
SELECT 1 AS RN, '0' AS PropertyDetailId, 'Select PropertyDetail' as PropertyName 
UNION 
SELECT 2 AS RN, PropertyDetailId,PropertyDetail.PropertyName 
FROM PropertyDetail 
     JOIN SiteDetail ON PropertyDetail.SiteDetailId = SiteDetail.SiteDetailId 
WHERE 
    PropertyDetail.IsActive = 1 
    AND PropertyDetail.SiteId = 6 
    AND SiteDetail.IsActive = 1 
    AND CustomerId = 0
ORDER BY RN, PropertyName
```

Another approach is to add a record on a client side before showing data in dropdown

Comment: Thanks. @Max Brodin.

Answer (score 0):

Just exclude what you don't want. 
Try this

```
SELECT '0' AS PropertyDetailId, 'Select PropertyDetail' as PropertyName 
    UNION SELECT PropertyDetailId,PropertyDetail.PropertyName 
    FROM PropertyDetail join SiteDetail ON 
    PropertyDetail.SiteDetailId = SiteDetail.SiteDetailId WHERE 
        PropertyDetail.IsActive = 1 
        AND PropertyDetail.SiteId = 6 
        AND SiteDetail.IsActive = 1 
        AND CustomerId = 0 
        AND PropertyDetailId <> 0
    ORDER BY PropertyName
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one. (Order By value Set to Top for 'SELECT PROPERTYDETAIL')

```
    SELECT '0' AS PROPERTYDETAILID
        ,'SELECT PROPERTYDETAIL' AS PROPERTYNAME

    UNION

    SELECT PROPERTYDETAILID
        ,PROPERTYDETAIL.PROPERTYNAME
    FROM PROPERTYDETAIL
    JOIN SITEDETAIL ON PROPERTYDETAIL.SITEDETAILID = SITEDETAIL.SITEDETAILID
    WHERE PROPERTYDETAIL.ISACTIVE = 1
        AND PROPERTYDETAIL.SITEID = 6
        AND SITEDETAIL.ISACTIVE = 1
        AND CUSTOMERID = 0
    ORDER BY CASE PROPERTYNAME WHEN   'SELECT PROPERTYDETAIL' THEN 1 END, PROPERTYNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   with aa as(
    SELECT '0' AS PropertyDetailId, 'Select PropertyDetail' as PropertyName 
    UNION SELECT PropertyDetailId,PropertyDetail.PropertyName 
    FROM PropertyDetail join SiteDetail ON 
    PropertyDetail.SiteDetailId = SiteDetail.SiteDetailId WHERE 
    PropertyDetail.IsActive = 1 
    AND PropertyDetail.SiteId = 6 
    AND SiteDetail.IsActive = 1 
    AND CustomerId = 0
    )
    Select * from aa 
    ORDER BY (case when PropertyDetailId='0' then PropertyDetailId else PropertyName end)
```